# How do we ensure log out from first device when we log in from other device in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-service, android-broadcast

Answer might vary depending on the server side enabled or not, my first thoughts are to write a service that makes a call to server to check what is the IMEI of the device most recently logged in. Problem is : As we can not set this service to make a call to server at every second due to performance issues of the application, what would be the vise way to solve this problem?

Comment: You just have to filter the logs wih the PID of the device

Answer (score 2):

What I've generally done is to have a session identifier in the user record in the database. Login generates a new identifier and it needs to accompany each request. When they log in from a second location a new identifier is generated. The first location will now get a "Your session has expired or you have logged in from a second location" error message.

An examle in PHP since most of my server side is done with CakePHP. A simplification of the User model:

```
User (
  id INTEGER,
  userid VARCHAR(32),
  password VARCHAR(40), -- SHA1
  key VARCHAR(40) -- SHA1 in size
)
```

The key is generated in my login method as:

```
$user['User']['key'] = sha1($user['User']['userid'] . time . rand(0, 1000));
```

This is just a SHA1 hash (40 chars wide) of the user's login name concatenated with the current epoch second and a random number between 0 and 1000. This goes in the database on the server and is returned to the client. The client appends ?key= to each request after login.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give any tiny example about this identifier?